# KeyboardAvoidingView hides view instead of showing them

Tags: react-native

I'm experiencing a very stupid behavior from `KeyboardAvoidingView`.
Basically every time I focus a `TextInput`, the screen seems to move of the same height (probably the keyboard height) whatever the position of the `TextInput`.
Meaning that if a view will be visible after the keyboard shows (and therefore moving the screen is not necessary) `KeyboardAvoidingView` still moves the screen up, hiding the `TextInput` behind the ActionBar (or simply outside of the screen).

I tried `KeyboardAwareScrollView` which works much better... only on iOS.
On Android it does not work at all, just no effects.

Comment: `KeyboardAvoidingView` has been a headache. I also found more success with `KeyboardAwareScrollView`. In my `AndroidManifest.xml`, I found `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the `<activity>` tag for the `MainActivity` did the trick even without `KeyboardAwareScrollView`. Note after changing the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you'll have to `react-native run-android` to rebuild.

Comment: Hey thanks! I read about this as well, but sadly I'm using Expo and i don't think I can edit the manifest

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate!

Comment: Try to add ScrollView inside the modal. (My text input is auto focus, without using KeyboardAvoidingView)